# Where does the Doctor take the TARDIS to get it repaired?

Tags: doctor-who, tardis

Where does the Doctor take the TARDIS to get it repaired? Like in the episode "The Eleventh Hour".

- He can't go to Gallifrey as it is Timelocked.
- He can't go to the past as technology isn't advanced enough.

If he goes to the future, where does he go?

Answer (score 12):

I believe he does most of the repairs himself, excepting what the Tardis can do with Self-Repair systems (as happens in '[The 11th Hour](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Eleventh_Hour_%28TV_story%29)')

We've seen that the Tardis has the ability to reconfigure it's internal layout, 'grown' new components (seen in [Journey to the Centre of the TARDIS](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Journey_to_the_Centre_of_the_TARDIS_%28TV_story%29)), and, at the end of the 11th Hour, even produce a new Sonic for him.  It appears that the Tardis has quite a few 'standard' repairs it can do without the Doctor having to be involved; regrowing damaged / lost rooms being an example.  This also ties back to an element that was cut from a few episodes, that Tardis' are **grown**. (E.g., cut from '[Journey's End](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Journey%27s_End_%28TV_story%29)'; "the Doctor hands his clone a coral-like piece of the TARDIS, telling him to grow his own.")

As you mention - there aren't many places he can get it repaired; he has been *on the run* in one sense or another for a long time. That being said, we have seen at least one; [Logopolis](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Logopolis_%28TV_story%29). Back when it was still around and functioning, they were going to fix his Chameleon circuit with Block Transfer Computation.  There may be other examples.

We've also seen him working on repairing parts of the Tardis in countless episodes; even companions have helped him from time to time.  Although, when he stole the Tardis, it was in the Repair shop, not all Time Lords necessarily have the same technical skills, and others may have needed to 'bring it to the shop' for repairs.  Clearly the Doctor has the ability to perform at least some, if not most (an exception being what the Logopolians were going to fix for him), repairs that it has needed, based on how often we've seen it damaged, and him repairing it.

Answer (score 0):

The TARDIS repairs itself, the Doctor has rarely done major repairs on the TARDIS himself.

As seen in various episodes in which the TARDIS redecorates itself, the earliest stated here in the [Wikipedia entry for TARDIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TARDIS):

> Baker, Bob; Martin, Dave (1 October 1977–22 October 1977). "Part 1".
> The Invisible Enemy. Doctor Who. BBC. "Number two control room has
> been closed for redecoration. I don't like the colour. ... That's the
> trouble with computers. Always think in black and white."

As well as the 11th Hour.

A TARDIS itself is actually a bioship that was grown on Gallifrey...

> TARDISes are bioships that are grown from a species of coral
> presumably indigenous to Gallifrey, as stated in "The Impossible
> Planet" (2006), and it can take years to complete one.

The TARDIS is able to reconfigure itself using the "architectural reconfiguration system" which was shown in "Journey to the Center of the TARDIS", when the salvagers take one of the components to it, which is grown inside of the TARDIS (which makes sense since it's a bioship).

Unfortunately as you mentioned there are no real places for the TARDIS to get repaired because Gallifrey is gone, but as previously shown the Doctor has been shown capable of doing at least some repairs to it...

He even goes as far as creating enough of a TARDIS console room to chase after House in which they use parts of different TARDISes (with help from Idris, the Doctor's TARDIS' personality) in the episode "[The Doctor's Wife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Doctor%27s_Wife)".

> The Doctor and Idris work together to construct a makeshift TARDIS
> from scraps, and then pursue House.

This shows with the proper resources and guides he can essentially repair the TARDIS himself, the problem now being that Iris isn't really there to help him if something were to seriously go wrong..

Comment: For reference, Idris is not an acronym.  It is the name of the person previously occupying the body into which the House put the TARDIS matrix.  As an unabbreviated proper noun, it takes Noun Case rather than ALL CAPS.

Answer (score 0):

It's a techno-organic sentient creature, technically, so it's able to grow itself back entirely, like a plant, or coral. Of course how long it takes depends on the damage. TARDIS's are supposed to have a symbiotic relationship with their Time Lord owners, so it's only natural they'd be able to heal and regenerate, pretty much like Time Lords themselves are able to do.

Comment: What's the source on the symbiotic relationship?